# Driving the Options of a Given Package from Another Package or Class in LaTeX3/expl3

Tags: latex3, expl3

I'm afraid I still don't get how I'm supposed to handle the communication of options among packages in a `LaTeX3/expl3` context. Let us say I have a package `pkg1` where I define an option `opt_pkg1` that is set in the document, but which is actually used just to drive the options (`opt1_pkg2`,`opt2_pkg2`...) with which another package `pkg2` is loaded from the first (`pkg1`). What's a correct way to do this by using `l3keys`?

I'll try to make my point clear by way of a small example, something akin to a semiMnotWE: There are missing declarations for some Booleans, besides other tidbits making it a not working example... It is supposed just to be able to convey my point. Observe that I have switched from `pkg1(2)` to `pkgA(B)` due to syntax requirements.

The basic message behind it is: In `pkgA` I define the options that allow me to set the typeface and the separate possibility to choose a sans face in the main document. Setting the typeface leads `pkgA` to load one or another extra package (`pkgB`) and, in this case, my choosing a sans face leads to loading `pkgB` with one or another option. Hope I've been able to make my point clear...

This is `pkgA.sty`, although in general -- in my case -- this will be a class file:

```
\ProvidesExplPackage{pkgA}{2013/08/20}{0.0} 
 {LaTeX2e/LaTeX3 package}

\RequirePackage{xparse,l3keys2e}% Needed?

\NewDocumentCommand\SetTBool { m }
 {
    \bool_set_true:c { g_pkgA_#1_bool }
 }

\keys_define:nn { pkgA }
{
    typeface .choice_code:n =
        { \SetTBool { \tl_use:N \l_keys_choice_tl } },
    typeface .generate_choices:n = { lucida, libertine },
    typeface .initial:n = libertine,

    sans-face .choice_code:n =
        { % Watch out! 
          % The next switch does not work as it is, but I guess it conveys my point
           \tl_if_eq:NnT \l_keys_choice_tl { sansbiolinum }
            {  
              % In this branch I set or pass (???) the { sansbiolinum = true } option to pkgB 
            }
        },
    sans-face .generate_choices:n = { sansbiolinum, sansmyriad }, 
} 

\DeclareDocumentCommand\DocumentSetup { +m }
 { \keys_set:nn { pkgA }{ #1 } }

\ProcessKeysOptions { pkgA }

\bool_if:NT \g_pkgA_lucida_bool { \RequirePackage{pkgB} }
```

Next comes `pkgB.sty`:

```
\ProvidesExplPackage{pkgB}{2013/08/20}{0.0} 
 {LaTeX2e/LaTeX3 package}

\RequirePackage{lucimatx}

\keys_define:nn { pkgB }
 {
    sansbiolinum .bool_set:N = \g_pkgB_sansbiolinum_bool,
 }

\ProcessKeysOptions { pkgB }    

\bool_if:NT \g_pkgB_sansbiolinum_bool 
  { \RequirePackage[osf]{biolinum} }
```

Lastly, in the "document" (.tex file), I have something like:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{pkgA}

\DocumentSetup{
   typeface = lucida,
   sans-face = sansbiolinum,
}

 \ProcessKeysOptions { pkgA }

 \begin{document}
 Blah, blah, blah.
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Could you edit in a more concrete example?  Something along the first lines of `pkg1` (if I understand the question correctly)?

Comment: As I understand it, you just want to pass options from one package to another. You shouldn't be assuming any internal structural relationship between the two, so should be passing the options as normal. Do I miss something?

Comment: Please, see the edit to my OP.

Comment: You can't use `pkg1` and `pkg2` as part of control sequence names. Please, edit them like `pkgI` and `pkgII` or something like that. They're good in module names for `\keys_define:nn`, but `\g_pkg2_sansbiolinum_bool` is illegal.

Comment: @egreg: Done. Thx.

Comment: What's the reason for using a secondary package?

Comment: @egreg: This is just a tiny snippet from a larger context. In the complete setting the secondary package does more than just loading a fonts-declaration package.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that each package uses `l3keys` internally should not affect at all how you pass load-time options: you should use the defined interfaces of `pkgB`. As described, `pkgB` only makes its options available at load time (we don't see the docs, but the way the code is written suggests there is no `\pkgBsetup`). As such, you should make available in `pkgA` an option which only works before `pkgB` is loaded: probably again a load-time option. This can then pass information to `pkgB` using `\PassOptionsToPackage` as normal.

Comment: Your answer seemed to me a bit cryptic, but finally I got everything I needed straight and I find the ``LaTeX3/expl3`` key-value experience to be much more satisfying than any of its  ``LaTeX2e`` counterparts.